# What does "climb to FL300" mean?

Tags: air-traffic-control

If you are flying at FL275 and the control center tells you to climb to FL300, what does that mean and what does the pilot have to do to meet that direction from the ATC?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly is unclear to you? Are you asking about the minimum rate of climb to comply with the instruction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "flight level" and "altitude"?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13204/what-is-the-difference-between-flight-level-and-altitude)

Comment: This could result in duplicate answers of this question since the question seems to be based on a missing fundamental.

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13204/what-is-the-difference-between-flight-level-and-altitude

Answer (score 5):

It means that the pilot must climb the aircraft from FL275 (27500 feet) up to FL300 (30000 feet) and then continue flying at that level. The pilot will read back the instruction to ATC, and then do it.

Comment: And of course maintains FL300 when reaching

Comment: @pcfreakxx Fair point :D Edited